# Can't center align p inside table cell?

Tags: html, css

I am doing vertical align so I put my `<p>` on table-cell, however when I am trying to center the texts, `text-align:center` doesn't affect them, but the div on my fourth box as you can see is centered? maybe it's because of the `display:table-cell`? this is my scss code:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div.top {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #ff99b3;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
div.top p {
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div.middle {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #ffff99;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
div.middle p {
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.bottom {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #eb99ff;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
div.bottom p {
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
div.length {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #99ffe6;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
div.length div {
  background: #ff99b3;
  vertical-align: -425px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top" style="text-align: center;">
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <strong>TOP</strong>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="middle">
  <p>
    <strong>MIDDLE</strong>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <p style="text-align:center;">
    <strong>BOTTOM</strong>

</div>

<div class="length">
  <div>
    <strong>ELEMENT</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/pwL5bgyt/6/)

I already put an inline style of css on `div` and `p` but still doesn't center the text

Comment: paste your html code also it will help to get perfect answer

Comment: I put table cell on it  becuase vertical align will not work if I remove table cell? what I want to happen is on each box, they are assigned top, middle,bottom

Comment: @dippas thanks. your code worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `table-cell` in `div` and remove `p`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%
}
.table > div {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 1%;
}
.top {
  background: #ff99b3;
  vertical-align: top
}
.middle {
  background: #ffff99;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.bottom {
  background: #eb99ff;
  vertical-align: bottom
}
.length {
  background: #99ffe6;
}
.length > div {
  background: #ff99b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="top">
    <strong>TOP</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <strong>MIDDLE</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <strong>BOTTOM</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="length">
    <div>
      <strong>ELEMENT</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click the word "Middle" and select "Inspect Element", then this will open up a tree of elements in your page. You can find pretty quick that the `<p>` is not full width. That is the problem.

Normally this would be solved by using `width:100%` or `margin:0 auto`. But that didn't work on the `<p>` element.

I think that part of your problem is you have a `table-cell` element (your `<p>`) but it is not contained within the `table-row` and `table` elements. Think of old-style `<table>`s and how they are normally set up.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you had elements in this setup (either using actual `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` or elements with CSS `display: table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`), alignment would be more easily customizable.

Specifically, I would suggest you keep your `<div>`s, and replace the `<p>` with `<table><tr><td>` and then you can put `width: 100%` on the `table` so that `text-align` would work as expected.

Comment: I tried to remove table cell but vertical align will not work on  each box

Comment: Your principle is right, but because CSS creates anonymous table objects where necessary, the solution is simpler than you think. In fact, one solution is simply to change the `div` display property from `inline-block` to `inline-table`.

Comment: Just to clarify, *"anonymous table objects"* is referring to the automatically added `<tbody>` and `<tr>`... is that correct?

Comment: Sort of. We're talking CSS here, so they're automatically added table-row-group and table-row objects rather than `<tbody>` and `<tr>` which are HTML elements. [Anonymous table objects in the CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#anonymous-boxes)